# Exiting while loop in winapi

Tags: winapi

My problem is this. I have check box which when checked starts while loop. At that while loop there is createprocess function. While checkbox is marked as checked, function repeats it self again and again. Problem is that while loop is running I can't push check box again to change it's values and stop the process. I think that here is needed something like two parallel process working at the same time, but I am not sure. My question would be:
* Is there a way to access my controls while while loop is running?
* Or maybe I should use something else instead of while process?

Suggestions or some kind of example would be appreciated.

Comment: Please produce a Minimum, Complete, Verifiable Example so that we can help you address your issue properly: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: you must not do any loops in window procedure. you need event based code. so not do loop - this is mistake. when checkbox checked/unchecked - you got notify about this - based on this notify and do some tasks

Comment: Questions aren't based on code so code is not important here. I am just  looking for options or advices and @RbMm gave me some.

Comment: any loops or waiting inside Window procedure is principal error. any message must be handled fast and return control.

Comment: You need [Programming Windows®, Fifth Edition](https://www.amazon.com/dp/157231995X).

Comment: @RbMm yes, well then i should go back too researh again. thank you for tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are running the loop in the same thread that owns the CheckBox, and that loop is blocking the thread from processing new messages.  That is why you are not able to uncheck the CheckBox (or do anything else with your UI).

You need to either:

1. move the loop to a worker thread.  When the CheckBox becomes checked, start the thread.  When the CheckBox becomes unchecked, stop the thread.  Do not block the dialog's thread at all.  This is the best option.
2. break apart your loop and make it event-driven.  When the CheckBox becomes checked, post a custom window message to yourself.  When you receive that message, if the CheckBox is still checked then perform *one* iteration of your loop and then post the message back to yourself again.  Repeat until the CheckBox becomes unchecked.  This option does not require any threads, but your UI will still be blocked during each individual iteration (but you will be able to uncheck the CheckBox in between iterations), unless...
3. Keep your existing loop code, but add an inner loop that calls `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` after `CreateProcess()` succeeds until the spawned process has exited.  While waiting, whenever `MsgWaitForMultipleObjects()` tells you that a new message is waiting, you can pump the message queue and dispatch any messages that are retrieved.  This is the least desirable option, but it requires the least amount of changes to existing code.

Comment: thank you @Remy Lebeau. By creating a thread i have achieved functionality I want